# SSRS report for multiple users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I want to create an ssrs report for all users in a call center. Their report will show needs to show each user their own data. How can I create an SSRS report that will show different data for each users it is sent to in a pdf format?

Comment: If you have the **Enterprise Edition**, you can use a **Data Driven Subscription** to send each user their own report. Check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in variable `User!UserID` to get the current user and pass that as a parameter to a stored procedure. You can find the variables in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).